# iOS 10.0.1 push notification custom sound not playing(mp3)

Tags: ios, push-notification

Hi guys i added sound file(mp3) to bundle and its working fine when i received push notification till iOS 9.2 but after updating to iOS 10.0.1 the latest iOS version tone is not playing

some one please help me with this problem

**Found solution**
before iOS 10.0.1 mp3 file is working
but in iOS 10.0.1 mp3 is not working **aiff** format is working

Comment: try to add this tone file to your project directly

Comment: as per the documentation file can also be in bundle

Comment: there are two file one is msg tone and other is ringer tone(29 seconds) small msg tone is working fine but ringer tone is not taking mobile custom tone is playing

Comment: Try bother variants witn/without bundle. Try to check file name

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: You may need to restart device as per this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7664290?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: i did restart many times it cannot solve and about code there will be no code payload has sound name and bundle has sound file so it should play automatically i am not understanding the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)

> Custom alert sounds are played by the iOS system-sound facility, so
>   they must be in one of the following audio data formats:
>
> Linear PCM, MA4 (IMA/ADPCM), µLaw, aLaw
>
> You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in
>   Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource
>   of the app bundle or to the Library/Sounds folder of your data
>   container.

They does not mention `MP3s`.

You can use the afconvert tool to convert sounds. For example, to convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound Submarine.aiff to IMA4 audio in a CAF file, use the following command in the Terminal app:

```
afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v
```

Comment: Ahh man great found the solution  iOS 10.0.1 mp3 file not working i just changed to "aiff" format its working now